# htaccess to permanently redirect from folder, but not subfolders, to home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect users trying to access www.mysite.com/folder or mysite.com/folder to the home page. BUT, I don't want it to apply if someone accesses no www or www.mysite.com/folder/subfolder OR when they access either no www or www.mysite.com/folder/awesome-page.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/?$
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=301,DPI]
```

Will redirect

`http://www.mysite.com/folder` or `http://mysite.com/folder` to

`http://www.mysite.com` or to `http://mysite.com`, but never when requested URL has 2 or more folders, like:

`http://www.mysite.com/folder/OtherFolder/...`

Comment: Hazah!! This seems to be working. Thank you VERY much Felipe!